# TV movie about a group of kids who explored a cave where their worst fears would manifest

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

The above is about all I can remember from it, except that I watched it as a kid in the '80s, possibly on ABC or NBC. Also, one of the kids' worst fears was a giant cheeseburger that looked like a monster and it was chasing them through the caves.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did you actually watch this back in the '80s, or more recently? If more recently, then when?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: i actually saw it as a kid in the 80s

Comment: Are you certain that this was a movie, rather than an episode of a TV series?

Comment: while it is a vague memory for some reason television movie is what really comes to mind and don't feel bad if I can't get an answer Ive literally been asking this question for 20 years

Answer (score 8):

This could be *[Making Contact](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089378/?ref_=tt_urv)*, a film directed by Roland Emmerich, released in 1985.

The central character is called Joey, who after the death of his father, is transported  to a fantasy realm. From a [review](https://themovieelite.com/making-contact-1985-kino-lorber-blu-ray-review/) of the bluray release of the film:

> Joey is transported to a spirit realm where he’s forced to enter into
> a labyrinth where he encounters bizarre creatures, including **a giant
> monster cheeseburger**. Some of the neighborhood kids get transported to
> the same place where they run a gauntlet of perils, and after a
> shocking encounter with the evil spirit, Joey’s fate takes a
> surprising turn.

The cheeseburger was the manifestation of the fears of one of the bullies, a fat kid nicknamed "Big Eater".

Comment: I would have to see it and see the scene where they're getting chased by the cheeseburger monster to make sure but I think after 20 years that quickly you just answered that question

Comment: @OmynsnPortents Valorum has posted a link to the fil on youtube. The cheeseburger monster appears at about 59:48